# Synaptic Package Manager doesn'd know about Snap (Gnome Software Center), and vice versa

Tags: package-management, software-center, synaptic

I use *Ubuntu Studio 20.04* (upgraded from *19.10*, upgraded from *18.04*).

I discovered, since *18.04*, there are a lot of apps from *Snap* (*Gnome Software Center*) that *Synaptic Package Manager* doesn't know, and vice versa.

I thought this had been fixed with the years, but... It is the same, today, with *20.04*.

Is it something *by default*?

Is there something wrong in my configuration?

How could we get both services work side by side?

Comment: Noting is wrong. Synaptics has nothing to do with snap. I son't think it will be ever "fixed".

Comment: @Pilot6 Thank you so much for your data!!! Now I understand the point. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both types of packages already do work side-by-side in Ubuntu Software.

Snap Store is deliberately snap-only. It's intended for other distros that don't use debs. You can use it in Ubuntu, but it's still going to be snap-only. Some folks get confused because LOOKS like Ubuntu Software (they both come from the same codebase), but it has a different intended use.

Synaptic is deliberately deb-only. It's intended for all distros that use use debs, and the developers seem to have no interest at the moment in changing that intent.

Comment: Thank you so much for your data!!! Now I understand the point. Thanks a lot!!!